# How to count row in database mysql and get the value, if null value = 0

Tags: php, mysql, database

I want to insert image to Database but I want to check if there is already stored image or not.
If no image before, update the database, if there is image in database, update database and unlink prev image.

```
$stmt = $db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM pr_journalist WHERE id='".$id."' AND foto='' ");
    
    
    if($stmt = 0) {
    
        // Insert image file name into database
            $insert = $db->query("UPDATE pr_journalist SET foto='".$fileName."' WHERE id='".$id."'");
        
                        
        unlink("uploads/".$foto);
           $statusMsg = 'ok';
       
        }else{
        // Insert image file name into database
            $insert = $db->query("UPDATE pr_journalist SET foto='".$fileName."' WHERE id='".$id."'");
       
                        
           $statusMsg = 'ok';
        
    }
```

With my above code, counting Row always make me to one if condition, although im trying to change to foto IS NOT NULL and change if condition to != 0 or foto IS NULL with if = 0.
It is like if ($stmt = 0) always got the same value from row count.

Comment: please use only **prepared statements with pararmeters** to prevent **sql injection**

Comment: @nbk since im new here, would you please tell me clearer?

Comment: i gave you all buzzwords to find your way around, but the canonical to that particular idea is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Answer (score 0):

To count rows you should not do $stmt = 0,

its,

```
$count=query->rowCount();
```

Comment: hello @niyamxsept thanks for your answer, should I change the select statement? or just IF statement?

Comment: Place this statement after $stmt query then do a if check by. If ($count=0)

Comment: sorry, I tried and nothing worked. If I follow you, the $stmt is not called by anything, $count=query->rowCount();  doesn't call $stmt

Comment: ok i give you a simple example , follow the rest :)  `$db=new PDO("mysql:host=localhost",dbname=yourdbname,"username","passoword"); $query=$db->query("select * from users where name=$name"); $query->execute(); $counter=$query->rowCount();`  now do if($counter==0)